# Returning values based on several conditions in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a simple table which contains 4 columns:

1. order id which is unique and can't be null
2. movie id which can't be null
3. rent_date which can't be null
4. return_date which **can** be null

I'm trying to return all movie ids which have at-least 1 of two conditions:

1. the same movie was ordered twice on the same date (as long as the return date isn't null)
2. the same movie was ordered on the same date as it was returned (2 different order ids - the rent date of the first movie id is the return date of the second movie id)

The table looks something like this:

```
order_id    movie_id    rent_date   return_date
1           1           2014-07-17  NULL
2           1           2014-07-18  NULL
3           1           2014-07-19  2014-07-17
4           2           2014-07-17  2014-07-18
5           2           2014-07-17  2014-07-18
6           3           2014-07-17  NULL
7           3           2014-07-18  2014-07-19
```

I want to return the following movie IDs:

- movie id 1 - because the rentdate in order 1 matches the return date in order 3
- movie id 2 - because it has the same rentdate in both order id 4 and order id 5

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `rent_date` can be later than `return_date` ?

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention.
rent date cannot be later than return date - it can however be equal.

Comment: so `Order 3` is typo error ?

Comment: it is, it should be 2014-07-17 or earlier. 
Sorry!!

Comment: Order 4 and 5 suggest that you have two copies of movie 2 (first one rented on 2014-07-17 and second one rented the same day without the first one being returned). Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

you can try like below

```
    select t1.rent_date,t1.movie_id  from t t1 join t t2 
     on t1.rent_date=t2.return_date and t1.movie_id=t2.movie_id and t1.order_id!=t2.order_id
     union
select t1.rent_date, t1.movie_id  from t t1
 where t1.return_date IS NOT NULL
  group by t1.rent_date,t1.movie_id
  having count(*)>1
```

Comment: Second query needs `AND return_date IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 0):

Create the Simple Table

```
declare @simple table
(
    order_id    int,
    movie_id    int,
    rent_date   date,
    return_date date
)
```

And some simple data

```
insert into @simple values
(1, 1, '2014-07-17', NULL),
(2, 1, '2014-07-18', NULL),
(3, 1, '2014-07-19', '2014-07-17'),
(4, 2, '2014-07-17', '2014-07-18'),
(5, 2, '2014-07-17', '2014-07-18'),
(6, 3, '2014-07-17', NULL),
(7, 3, '2014-07-18', '2014-07-19')
```

the query

```
select  distinct movie_id
from    @simple t
where   exists  -- Rule 1
    (
        select  rent_date
        from    @simple x
        where   return_date is not null
        and movie_id    = t.movie_id
        group by rent_date
        having count(*) = 2
    ) 
or  exists  -- Rule 2
    (
        select  *
        from    @simple x
        where   x.movie_id  = t.movie_id
        and x.rent_date = t.return_date
    )
```

Comment: Rule 1 doesn't need to be so complex. Table `t` already has one row, table `x` just needs to contain one other such row.  Rule 2 needs `AND t.order_id <> x.order_id`

Answer (score 0):

1) the same movie was ordered twice on the same date (as long as the return date isn't null)

This can be done by grouping on movie-id and rent-date and adding the having argument (HAVING COUNT(*) >= 1)

2) The same movie was ordered on the same date as it was returned (2 different order ids - the rent date of the first movie id is the return date of the second movie id)

This can be done by joining the table on itself and add two conditions to the join statement. tabele1.movie_id = table2.movie_id And tabele1.rent_date = tabele2.return_date. Also add that both order-ids should be different

This will result in two tables of which you can collect the movie_id and rent-date. If you combine the two tables with a UNION (not a UNION ALL), you get the unique results.

Out of my head, it will result into something like the code below.

```
SELECT movie_id, rent_date 
FROM movies table1
JOIN movies table2 ON tabele1.movie_id = table2.movie_id 
                   AND tabele1.rent_date = tabele2.rent_date 
GROUP BY movie_id, rent_date    
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

UNION

SELECT movie_id, rent_date 
FROM movies table1
JOIN movies table2 ON tabele1.movie_id = table2.movie_id 
                   AND tabele1.rent_date = tabele2.return_date
                   AND tabele1.order_id <> tabele2.order_id
GROUP BY movie_id, rent_date
```

To get the unique movie-ids, you can use this as a CTE or Inner-Query and add a GROUP BY on movie_id, rent_date.

Comment: You can't group by one column and select two columns. The rent_date must be within an aggregate function or in the group by...

Comment: I thought I had corrected that half an hour ago.. guess I have to edit it again :/

Comment: Using a JOIN as well as GROUP BY HAVING in the first query is redundant. If remove the JOIN.

Comment: Similarly, why the GROUP BY in the second query? The UNION will deduplicate everything any way.

Comment: True,... but I choose to be stubborn and not change the code... again. :P